# Add a class tag to "the changable content DIV of the chosen <li>"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some menus in a `ul`. When a user clicks one of those menu, a content in one DIV will change.

```
----------

<ul id="choice">

    <li> fisrt choice 
      <div> hidden div that is going to show in #zen-content </div>
    </li>

    <li> 
      <div> hidden div that is going to show in #zen-content </div>
    </li>

    ....   
    ....

</ul>   


<div id="zen-content"></div>
....
....
....
```

---

---

---

**I want that**: when the hidden div from one of the `<li>` has been transfered to the blank div (which it is `#zen-conten`), then the div inside the `#zen-conten` will have a class of `easyzoom easyzoom--overlay`

**It will look like this:**

```
 <div id="zen-content">
     <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay"> it is a hidden DIV from li </div>
 </div>
```

---

---

Here is the Jquery I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zen-content').html($('#choice li:first').html()); 

    $('#choice li').click(function(event) {
        $('#zen-content').html( $(this).html());
    }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to your `<div>` element from the selected `<li>` element using the `addClass` method from **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#zen-content').html($('#choice li:first').html()); 

  $('#choice li').click(function(event) {
    $('#zen-content').html( $(this).html());
    $('#zen-content').find('div').addClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. But how about the "first" choice of li? I need to have that class too for the first li. $('#zen-content').html($('#choice li:first').html());

Comment: you can add the same statement just after you have loaded your first `<li>` element:
`$('#zen-content').html($('#choice li:first').html()); 
$('#zen-content').find('div').addClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');`
But I don't advice to repeat you self and you should find a common design to only write it once :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code also and see live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7N3gW/

```
<ul id="choice">

    <li> fisrt choice 
      <div> first </div>
    </li>

    <li> secnd
      <div>second</div>
    </li>

</ul> 

<div id="zen-content"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice li").click(function(){
        $("#zen-content").html($(this).find("div").html());
    });
});
```